# "Whom would you offer the ride?"

Tags: grammar, questions

I was wondering if this question is accepted grammatically:

> 1. "**Whom** would you offer the ride?"

Some people say that the preposition 'to' should be added in this sentence:

2. "**To whom** would you offer the ride?"

or,

3. "**Whom** would you offer the ride **to**?"

Could anyone please help me?

Thanks in advance,
Oodo

Comment: Some people are correct.  The original is probably technically valid, but sounds "off".

Comment: I suspect that there is a tendency to resist the preposing or fronting of an indirect object, which is what your first example is sorta doing: *"Whom(i) would you offer __(i) the ride?"* Many times, the fronting of an indirect object is significantly less acceptable than the fronting of a direct object. -- Now, your adding a "to" (*"To whom would you offer the ride?"*) changes the construction, so that it is not an indirect object that is being fronted but rather it is a PP that is being fronted.

Comment: (cont.) And in that last example (*"Whom would you offer the ride to?"*), the complement of a PP is being fronted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The question is not so much about the usage of "whom", I think, but rather, the use of "to".

> The verb 'offer' can have two objects ; You would offer / him / the ride. If this sentence is changed into a question, it will be like this ; Whom would you offer the ride? In this context I can't understand why Preposition 'to' should be added into this question... - tasmantiger comment above.

Indeed, in your sentence "To whom would you offer the ride?", the verb "offer" takes two objects: "whom" and "ride". The point is that one (the ride) is a **direct object**, while the other (whom) is an **indirect object**.

We can see this more clearly if the sentence is written (more simply?) with the indirect object *after* the verb:

> You would offer the ride to whom?

Now we can see that "to" serves to identify "whom" as the indirect object. The "ride" is offered directly and has no need of a preposition. So, if we move "whom" back to the front of the sentence, it  either takes its "to" with it, to show it's an indirect object...

> To whom would you offer the ride?

... or (and to be more relaxed about the structure - thanks, keshlam) you can leave the "to" at the end:

> Whom would you offer the ride to?

For more information, see here: *[Write.com - direct and indirect objects](http://www.write.com/writing-guides/general-writing/grammar/direct-and-indirect-objects/)*.

Comment: "Whom would you offer the ride to" is also valid, so I agree that this is the correct answer.

Comment: Semantically speaking, _to whom_ is the indirect object, but syntactically it is not—it's a prepositional phrase. That makes all the difference in the world (see F.E.’s comment to the question, which really is the best answer given so far). IOs and PPs have different properties and act very differently.

Answer (score 1):

If you're bothering to use "whom" (correct, but formal/Standard English), the examples including "to" are preferable.

You could argue that "Whom would you give the ride?" is a construction where the "to" is simply dropped ("[To] whom would you give the ride?") and would be understood, but if you're writing in the formal/Standard English you might as well use the unambiguously correct "to whom".

"Who are you giving a ride?" is common in casual speech, but not correct Standard English. "To whom are you giving a ride?" is correct (but would sound formal when spoken). "Whom are you giving a ride?" is an unhappy medium, arguably not correct but too formal for casual use.

Comment: There is a sentence like this ; "Whom will you give a ride?"                        Why can't the question word "whom" be used as Indirect Object of the verb 'give', without using Preposition 'to'?   In other words, we can analyze the above sentence having two objects ; 'you will give / whom (=IO) / a ride (=DO)', I think.  Can you get what I meant?

Comment: @tasmantiger Look at it in the case of a different sentence: "*Whom are you talking?" This sentence makes no sense at all without "to". If you rearrange your original question in a statement form, it would be: "*You offer a ride to [John].*" Without "to", the sentence doesn't make sense. "*You offer a ride [John].*"

Comment: Hi, Catija   Without "to" , the sentence does make sense. "You offer John a ride."

Comment: @Catija Not true at all. You're misrearranging the sentence. The unfronted version of “Whom would you offer a ride?” is “You offer John a ride”, which is perfectly fine. _Offer_ is ditransitive, which _talk_ is not (it's intransitive in this usage), and “Whom are you talking?” is not a valid comparison.

Comment: Also, there is no dropped _to_ in the sentence given here—pronouns and proper names (and to a lesser degree all noun phrases) just have the innate ability to act as indirect objects. “I gave him a ride” is not an informal or shortened version of “I gave to him a ride”. Note how, in an unfronted statement, the bare indirect object normally _precedes_ the direct object, while the marked IO (with _to_) acts as a bog-standard prepositional phrase and _follows_ the DO. They're fundamentally different syntactic elements.

Answer (score 1):

> [**whom**](https://www.google.com/search?sourceid=navclient&aq=&oq=whom+de&ie=UTF-8&rlz=1T4VRHB_enUS620US620&q=whom+definition&gs_l=hp..0.0l2j0i10l2j0.0.0.5.7989291...........0.mN_m1nCGd5w&gws_rd=ssl) *pronoun*: used instead of “who” as the object of a verb or preposition. (Google)

According to traditional Latinate grammar, ‘who’ forms the subjective case and so should be used in subject position in a sentence, e.g., “*who painted this*?” The form whom, on the other hand, forms the objective case and so should be used in object position in a sentence, e.g., “*whom do you think we should elect*?” or, in the OP’s example, ”*to whom would you offer the ride*?"

The use of ‘whom’ has steadily and significantly declined and is now largely restricted to formal contexts. The more frequent practice in modern English is to use who instead of whom and, where applicable, to put the preposition at the end of the sentence (*who would you offer the ride to*?). Currently, such usage is acceptable English, but in formal writing the distinction is preferable.

Comment: Um, no, that's not actually according to formal grammar; that's according to traditional Latinate grammar. Formal grammar has already consigned _whom_ to the hospice, where [its novel adaptations](http://itre.cis.upenn.edu/~myl/languagelog/archives/001437.html) (like using _whom_ instead of _who_ as the subject of a formal request, because _whom_ makes it more formal) are being studied by sociolinguists.

Comment: Thank you, Eva     The verb 'offer' can have two objects ; You would offer / him  / the ride.   If this sentence is changed into a question, it will be like this ; Whom would you offer the ride?   In this context  I can't understand why Preposition 'to' should be added into this question.

Comment: I think the use of "to" is optional , not compulsory !

Comment: Thanks to your  useful advice, my English seems to be getting better!